# Error startup eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse

When starting Eclipse Luna Runtime workbench, This error occurs after installing a plugin to design uml2

LOG:

```
!SESSION 2016-04-21 08:01:09.367 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=es_CO
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2016-04-21 08:01:43.119
!MESSAGE [SCR] Enabling components of bundle org.eclipse.ui.trace did not complete in 30000 ms 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2016-04-21 08:01:43.120
!MESSAGE [SCR - WorkThread] Timeout occurred! Thread was blocked on processing [QueuedJob] WorkPerformer: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager@17f63d6; actionType 1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2016-04-21 08:01:48.247
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.0.v20140318-2214"; singleton:="true" [id=79] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: A plugin? Which one? Is it compatible with luna?

Comment: Worth trying to run with `eclipse -clean` to see if that has resolved the problem.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, i run eclipse -clean, but it did not work, i install the plugin uml2 http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=